# ValueError: math domain error.. No root of negative number

Tags: python

My python always gives me this error..

There is no root of negative number because all bits inside are squared..help!

```py
    elif coordNumber == "4":
        fourInputXOne = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the first co-ordinate "))
        fourInputYOne = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the first co-ordinate "))
        print ("")
        fourInputXTwo = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the second co-ordinate "))
        fourInputYTwo = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the second co-ordinate "))
        print ("")
        fourInputXThree = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the third co-ordinate "))
        fourInputYThree = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the third co-ordinate "))
        print ("")
        fourInputXFour = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the fourth co-ordinate "))
        fourInputYFour = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the fourth co-ordinate "))
        print ("")

        print ("Here are the co-ordinates you have entered:")
        print ("1: (",fourInputXOne,",",fourInputYOne,")")
        print ("2: (",fourInputXTwo,",",fourInputYTwo,")")
        print ("3: (",fourInputXThree,",",fourInputYThree,")")
        print ("4: (",fourInputXFour,",",fourInputYFour,")")

        sideOneLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXTwo-fourInputXOne)^2 + (fourInputYTwo-fourInputYOne)^2 )
        sideTwoLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXThree-fourInputXTwo)^2 + (fourInputYThree-fourInputYTwo)^2 )
        sideThreeLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXFour-fourInputXThree)^2 + (fourInputYFour-fourInputYThree)^2 )
        sideFourLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXOne-fourInputXFour)^2 + (fourInputYOne-fourInputYFour)^2 )
```

Error with the sidelengths bit.

Comment: Why are you logically XORing your values? See [binary-bitwise-operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations)

Answer (score 1):

in python you use `a**b` to square not `a^b`

the caret symbol is a binary XOR operator

```
elif coordNumber == "4":
    fourInputXOne = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the first co-ordinate "))
    fourInputYOne = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the first co-ordinate "))
    print ("")
    fourInputXTwo = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the second co-ordinate "))
    fourInputYTwo = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the second co-ordinate "))
    print ("")
    fourInputXThree = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the third co-ordinate "))
    fourInputYThree = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the third co-ordinate "))
    print ("")
    fourInputXFour = int(input ("Please enter the x value of the fourth co-ordinate "))
    fourInputYFour = int(input ("Please enter the y value of the fourth co-ordinate "))
    print ("")

    print ("Here are the co-ordinates you have entered:")
    print ("1: (",fourInputXOne,",",fourInputYOne,")")
    print ("2: (",fourInputXTwo,",",fourInputYTwo,")")
    print ("3: (",fourInputXThree,",",fourInputYThree,")")
    print ("4: (",fourInputXFour,",",fourInputYFour,")")

    sideOneLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXTwo-fourInputXOne)**2 + (fourInputYTwo-fourInputYOne)**2 )
    sideTwoLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXThree-fourInputXTwo)**2 + (fourInputYThree-fourInputYTwo)**2 )
    sideThreeLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXFour-fourInputXThree)**2 + (fourInputYFour-fourInputYThree)**2 )
    sideFourLength = math.sqrt((fourInputXOne-fourInputXFour)**2 + (fourInputYOne-fourInputYFour)**2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you logically XORing your values?

Printing the offending numbers:

```
print( (fourInputXTwo-fourInputXOne)^2 )   # you can see its negative
```

or experimenting:

```
print(6^2)       # prints 4  - because 0b110^0b010 == 0b100
print(6**2)      # prints 36 - because 6**2 = 6*6 = 36
```

would have shown you that what you do wrong.

See [binary bitwise operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) for the full documentation.